# How can I use just the DictionaryAdapter from Castle Core 2.5.2?

Tags: c#, castle, castle-dictionaryadapter

I want to use just the DictionaryAdapter from Castle Core 2.5.2 in an old app that already uses Castle Core 1.2. Is there a way to keep apart the common parts of these libraries, except compiling just DictionaryAdapter from source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try first upgrading Castle.Core to 2.5.2, but your problem is that this will drag other dependencies. You can try compiling DictionaryAdapter from source, it's fairly independent from the rest of Castle.Core so it shouldn't be much trouble.

Comment: or just use the older version of DA... which is an separate assembly

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic: you said the new version is better :D http://kozmic.pl/2010/07/05/castle-windsor-2-5hellip-the-final-countdown-ndash-beta-1-released/

Comment: hehe. Well if the old one is enough for you and you don't want to build the custom one, than go for it :)

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic: it's much more interesting to build the newer one.

Comment: Ok then you have your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Since I have just the Express version of VS2010, I was tempted to use **ilmerge** to expose just the `DictionaryAdapter` namespace, but one thing led to another, and I took another route, since `Castle.Core.Smtp` is present in both versions: I started from `Castle.Core.dll` 2.5.2.0 and simply renamed the first part of the namespaces from `Castle` to `Castle252`, so I can use it along `Castle.Core` 1.2.0.0 without any conflict:

[How to Change Namespace of .NET Assembly?](http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/1/30/how-to-change-namespace-of-net-assembly.html)